# Textboxes are hidden when using onchange() at dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

On first load textboxes are hidden when using onchange() at dropdown but shown up with proper value after selecting a value. Why its hidding on first load? Some suggestions please !

Textbox Employee Name,Department Code,Designation Code are hidden on first load. but shown up with proper value after selecting from dropdown.

**Javascript**

```
function godata(){

var eid=document.getElementById("empid").value;
document.deduct.action="deductions.jsp?empid="+eid;
document.deduct.method="post";
document.deduct.submit();
}
```

**JSP**

```
GetEmpData data= new GetEmpData();
ArrayList list= data.getEmpData();
Iterator itr = list.iterator();
while (itr.hasNext()){
Employee em=(Employee)itr.next();

Employee Code <select id="empid" name="empid" onchange="godata()">
<option value="0">--</option>
<option value="<%=em.getEmpid()%>"><%=em.getEmpid()%></option>
</select><%}%>

String id= request.getParameter("empid");
GetEmpDataById data1=new GetEmpDataById();
ArrayList dataList= data1.getEmpDataById(id);
Iterator itr1=dataList.iterator();
while(itr1.hasNext()){
Employee emp=(Employee)itr1.next();



Employee Name<input type="text"  name="empname" value="<%=emp.getEmpname()%>" readonly="yes"">
Department Code <input type="text" name="deptcode" value="<%=emp.getDeptcode()%>" readonly="yes">
Designation Code <input type="text" name="desncode" value="<%=emp.getDesncode()%>" readonly="yes">
<%}%>
```

Comment: none of the code above replicates the behaviour you have described, please create a [MCVE]

Answer (score 0):

You are calling function only after `onchange()` instead call the function while `window.onload()` in javascript or `document.ready()` if you are using jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks but problem solved, actually form was under while loop that why that weird thing was happening. 
Now i declared string for every value, outside the form and its working properly.
    Like Below :

```
String name=""; 
while(itr1.hasNext()){
Employee emp=(Employee)itr1.next();
name=emp.getEmpname();
desn=emp.getDesncode();
dept=emp.getDeptcode(); 
}
<input type="text" name="empname" value="<%=name%>" readonly="yes">
```